# expression must be a modifiable lvalue char array c

Tags: c, funciones, variables

Tengo la siguiente función, para invertir una línea de texto:

```
char *reverse(char line[]){
   char *rever [strlen(line)];
   for (int i = 0; i < strlen(line); i++){
     rever[strlen(line)-i]=line[i];
   }
   return rever;
   }
```

la llamo en este fragmento de código:

```
while(fgets(line, 128, source)!=NULL) {
   char *rever[strlen(line)];
   rever= reverse(line);
   printf("%s",rever);
   fputs("%d",rever);
}
```

y al compilar con ubuntu me salen los siguientes errores:

```
step5.c: In function ‘reverse’:
step5.c:8:23: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
  rever[strlen(line)-i]=line[i];
                       ^
step5.c:10:8: warning: return from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
 return rever;
step5.c:10:8: warning: function returns address of local variable [-Wreturn-local-addr]
step5.c: In function ‘main’:
step5.c:31:10: error: assignment to expression with array type
     rever= reverse(line);
step5.c:32:14: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char **’ [-Wformat=]
     printf("%s",rever);
step5.c:33:16: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘fputs’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     fputs("%d",rever);
In file included from step5.c:1:0:
/usr/include/stdio.h:626:12: note: expected ‘FILE * restrict {aka struct _IO_FILE * restrict}’ but argument is of type ‘char **’
 extern int fputs (const char *__restrict __s, FILE *__restrict __stream)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vamos por partes:

```
char *rever [strlen(line)];
```

Estas declarando una **formación de punteros a caracter**, que no es lo que tu pretendes. Lo que tu quieres hacer es

```
char rever[strlen(line)];
```

Lo siguiente:

```
return rever;
```

Teniendo en cuenta que `rever` es una **variable automática**, cuyo tiempo de vida está limitado al tiempo que tarde en ejecutarse tu función, terminarás devolviendo un puntero a una zona de memoria que ya no contiene lo que tu esperas.

Adicionalmente, utilizar una variable como tamaño para una formación está permitido en C99, pero es **opcional** en C11. Asumo que estás en C99 :-)

Luego, en el `while( )`, vuelves a cometer el mismo error:

```
char *rever[strlen(line)];
rever= reverse(line);
```

con lo que vuelves a reservar una formación de punteros a char ... e intentas asignarle el valor devuelto por tu función `reverse( )`, que es una operación no compatible y lo que te produce el error que indicas.

La forma correcta de hacer lo que quieres sería utilizar memoria dinámica, quedando tal que así:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

...

char *reverse(char line[]){
  char *rever = malloc(strlen(line)+1);

  for (int i = 0; i < strlen(line); i++){
    rever[strlen(line)-i]=line[i];
  }

  rever[strlen(line)) = 0; // MUY IMPORTANTE el 0 final.

  return rever;
}

...

while(fgets(line, 128, source)!=NULL) {
  char *rever;
  rever= reverse(line);
  printf("%s",rever);
  fputs("%d",rever);
}
```

Observa que no realizamos el mas mínimo control de posibles errores: es posible que no se pueda obtener el bloque de memoria solicitado.

Answer (score 0):

La variable `rever` la estas definiendo como `char * rever[strlen[line)]` lo que significa que rever es una arreglo de punteros  a char. Luego, tratas de asignar a este arreglo un puntero a una cadena devuelta por la función `reverse (char *reverse)` . Lo correcto es  que hagas `rever[0]=reverse(line)`, pero ¿que vas a hacer con todos los demás `strlen(line) - 1` punteros?, Para evitar tener un arreglo de punteros solo define uno:

```
   char * rever=reverse(line);
```

y borra la anterior y la que tienes en la funcion `reverse`; solo debe ser   `char* rever=new char[strlen(line)+1];` y seria bueno que al final del bucle hagas `rever[strlen(line)]=0;` para asegurarte que sea una cadena finalizada considerando que estás moviendo byte por byte;