# Destruccion de variables automaticas en C

Tags: c

En [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/326277/expression-must-be-a-modifiable-lvalue-char-array-c?rq=1) pregunta del foro la cual visite por un problema totalmente externo al cariz de esta pregunta, vi una respuesta en la que se menciona algo bastante interesante (concretamente la respuesta de trauma). En una parte del codigo del usuario que hace la pregunta (francesc), este retorna la referencia a una cadena en una funcion (o al menos esa era su intencion)  y en la respuesta se pone lo siguiente ...

> Teniendo en cuenta que rever es una variable automática, cuyo tiempo de vida está limitado al tiempo que tarde en ejecutarse tu función, terminarás devolviendo un puntero a una zona de memoria que ya no contiene lo que tu esperas.

Esto tiene total sentido, sin embargo, me puse a revisar y paso algo un poco inesperado ...

codigo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *cadena();


char *cadena(){
    char *cadena = "Hola";
    return cadena;
}

int main(){
    int arreglo[20];
    char *cadena2 = cadena();

    printf("%s", cadena2);
    return 0;
}
```

salida:

```
Hola
```

Basicamente aun cuando la funcion retorna la referencia a un arreglo que se supone que ya no existe y que ademas no carga en memoria dinamica como si lo hace en la respuesta de @trauma, la cadena se retorna normalmente ... Teniendo esto en cuenta, la pregunta seria: por que ocurre esto? no se supone que el valor de retorno de cadena deberia de morir un vez terminada la funcion?

Con respecto a esto tengo una suposicion: cuando se realiza este tipo de asignacion realmente el compilador C (en mi caso gcc 9.3.0, estoy en ubuntu en estos momentos) carga `cadena` en memoria dinamica y es por ello que aun existe llegar a la linea 16.

Edicion final: he estado haciendo muchas pruebas y llegue a la siguiente conclusion ... Por lo visto, cuando se crean arreglos como punteros 'crudos', en funciones, su valor persiste despues de la finalizacion de la misma, en caso contrario, no.

ejemplo 1:

***codigo :***

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int *arreglo();


int *arreglo(){
    int *array = (int *) calloc(sizeof(int), 2);
    array[0] = 1;
    array[1] = 2;
    printf("referencia a array desde funcion <main> %i\n", array);
    return array;
}

int main(){
    printf("referencia a array desde funcion <main> %i\n", arreglo());
    return 0;
}
```

***salida:***

```
referencia a array desde funcion <main> 642618016
referencia a array desde funcion <main> 642618016
```

ejemplo 2:

***codigo :***

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int *arreglo();


int *arreglo(){
    int array[2] ;
    array[0] = 1;
    array[1] = 2;
    printf("referencia a array desde funcion <main> %i\n", array);
    return array;
}

int main(){
    printf("referencia a array desde funcion <main> %i\n", arreglo());
    return 0;
}
```

***salida:***

```
referencia a array desde funcion <main> -258186320
referencia a array desde funcion <main> 0
```

Si bien esto lo estoy comprobando con ejemplos, puede que esto este funcionando por muchas casualidades (por desgracia, esto ya me ha pasado (^ _ ^) ), asi que estaria bien que alguien que supiera confirmara todo esto

Comment: la función `cadena` te retorna una variable (o puntero) creada en la misma función, el valor de ese puntero pasa a tu variable `cadena2` y finalmente la imprimes, no veo donde estaría el error. No es como si hicieras un `free(cadena2)`

Comment: Estoy 'metiendo' en cadena2 la referencia a una seria de caracteres que, por haber sido creados en una funcion, es decir, ser locales, ya no deberian de existir, en otras palabras, cadena2 no deberia de apuntar a nada ...

Comment: pero estas retornando el valor, es lo mismo que si creas una función que genera números aleatorios y luego los retornas para usarlos después.

Comment: No, estoy retornando la referencia a la cadena (char *cadena()) ademas de que la unica forma de acceder a un arreglo es a traves de su referencia, en otras palabras, si no me equivoco no es posible retornar o enviar un arreglo por valor (si es asi, por favor corrijeme)

Comment: bueno, tal vez me estoy saltando algo, esperemos a que otros den su opinión

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Teniendo esto en cuenta, la pregunta seria: por que ocurre esto? no se supone
> que el valor de retorno de cadena deberia de morir un vez terminada la
> funcion?

Tomemos tu funcion:

```
char *cadena(){
    char *cadena = "Hola";
    return cadena;
}
```

Y veamos el assembler que esta genera:

```
.LC0:
        .string "Hola"
cadena():
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

Si te fijas, la cadena `"Hola"` se guarda afuera de la funcion. **Es como si
fuera una variable que marcaste como `static`, o una variable global**. Por eso
es que puedes acceder a ella afuera de la funcion, esta no se destruye. Esto es
lo que se suele hacer con las cadenas literales.

Es equivalente a esto:

```
char *cadena(){
    static const char[] foo = {'H', 'o', 'l', 'a', '\0'};
    char *cadena = (char*) foo;
    return cadena;
}
```

> Con respecto a esto tengo una suposicion: cuando se realiza este tipo de
> asignacion realmente el compilador C (en mi caso gcc 9.3.0, estoy en ubuntu en
> estos momentos) carga cadena en memoria dinamica y es por ello que aun existe
> llegar a la linea 16.

Mas bien guarda la cadena en la seccion `text` de tu ejecutable (Puede que este recordando mal el nombre).

---

---

Con esto:

> Edicion final: he estado haciendo muchas pruebas y llegue a la siguiente
> conclusion ... Por lo visto, cuando se crean arreglos como punteros 'crudos',
> en funciones, su valor persiste despues de la finalizacion de la misma, en
> caso contrario, no.

Supongo que te refieres a este ejemplo:

```
int *arreglo(){
    int *array = (int *) calloc(sizeof(int), 2);
    array[0] = 1;
    array[1] = 2;
    printf("referencia a array desde funcion <main> %i\n", array);
    return array;
}
```

Que se limpien luego de que se acabe la funcion solo aplica para las variables
que estan en el stack. Si usas `calloc`, estas asignando memoria en el heap, y
esta estara ahi hasta que tu la liberes usando `free`.

---

---

> Si bien esto lo estoy comprobando con ejemplos, puede que esto este
> funcionando por muchas casualidades (por desgracia, esto ya me ha pasado (^ _
> ^) ), asi que estaria bien que alguien que supiera confirmara todo esto

Las variables del stack mueren al salir de su scope (los `{}`). Estas son las
que declaras normalmente:

```c
{
    int a;
    float b;

    double* c;
}

// Aqui ya no puedes usarlas
```

Luego estan las variables estaticas dentro de las funciones, que duraran desde
que son inicializadas, hasta que termine el programa.

```
int foo() {
    // Inicializada en la primera llamada a la funcion
    static int bar = 10;
}
```

Estan las variables globales que duraran todo el programa, y finalmente esta la
memoria que tu asignes usando `malloc` y `calloc`, que estara disponible hasta
que tu la liberes usando `free`.

Answer (score 4):

Lo que sucede es que el literal `"Hola"` es guardado en la *memoria de solo lectura* mientras que la variable `cadena` se guarda en el *stack*. Lo que se guarda en dicha variable es la dirección de memoria de la cadena.

En general, si la cadena está en la definición de un arreglo, se ubicará en el stack también:

```
char[] saludo = "Hola";
```

Y si se almacenan en un puntero irá a la memoria de solo lectura.

```
char* saludo = "Hola";
```

No es algo seguro ya que varía según el compilador.

Fuentes:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/349030
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2589963
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14468729/13419694

Answer (score 3):

Quizás la duda la tengas debido a que las cadenas que declaras son estáticas, imagina que cuando compilas tu programa todas las cadenas que declares `"de esta forma"` tienen que ir dentro de tu binario si no ¿de donde las vas a sacar?.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *cadena() 
{
    
    char *cadena_estatica = "Cadena Interna";
    return cadena_estatica;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *sigue_viva = cadena();
    printf("%s", sigue_viva);
}
```

entonces cuando haces la asignación
`char *cadena_estatica = "Cadena Interna"`

estás igualando el puntero a una cadena estática la cual vive en tu binario y vive por toda la ejecución del programa; cuando finalmente la retornas simplemente estás pasando la dirección de memoria de la cadena estática, por lo que sabemos por hecho que es un espacio de memoria válido.

Ahora creemos la cadena nosotros mismos dentro de la función y de forma programática:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>


char *nuevo() 
{
    char interna[21];
    for(int i = 0; i<=19; i++)
        interna[i] = 'a';
    interna[20] = '\0';
    return interna;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("%s\n", nuevo());
}
```

y el programa falla ya que ahora estás apuntando a una página que ya sido descartada.