# Segmentation fault con strncat

Tags: c

Tengo el siguiente código que me da un error de segmentación al utilizar strcat o strncat y me gustaría saber qué está pasando porque no entiendo qué estoy haciendo mal. Gracias

```
int main (void) {
char *word = malloc(46);
if(word == NULL)
{
    return 1;
}
word ="z";
char c = 'z';

//for(int i = 0; i < 45; i++)
//{
    strncat(word, &c, 1);
    //strcat(word, &c);
    //printf("%i\n",hash(word));

//}

free(word);
}
```

Comment: sugerencia para futuras preguntas: incluir el mensaje de error completo, una traza más amplia, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te recomiendo que aprendas a compilar con el Address Sanitizer, este te puede
ayudar a diagnosticar rápidamente este tipo de problemas. Al usarlo, obtenemos
el siguiente error.

```
==3980==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: global-buffer-overflow on address 0x7ff60c5344a2 at pc 0x7ff60c4d06c8 bp 0x008a743ff010 sp 0x008a743ff058
```

El error es un buffer overflow, eso significa que estas escribiendo mas allá de
donde tienes asignada memoria. No solo eso, sino que se lo estas haciendo en un
global.

Fíjate en tu código, primero asignas la memoria de `word`:

```cpp
char *word = malloc(46);
if(word == NULL)
{
    return 1;
}
```

Y inmediatamente después, reasignas `word` a que apunte a una cadena literal (Que seria como si apuntaras a una cadena constante que se guarda en una variable global, mas detalles en mi respuesta a [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/469881/destruccion-de-variables-automaticas-en-c/469943#469943)).

```cpp
word ="z";
```

El problema radica en que cuando tratas de escribir a `word`

```
char c = 'z';
strncat(word, &c, 1);
```

Ya no estas escribiendo a la memoria que asignaste originalmente, sino a un
buffer que se asigno a una cadena literal (Que puede estar en memoria de solo
lectura, causando el SIGSEGV).

Y no solo eso, sino que luego tratas de liberar la memoria a ese buffer, que si
no anterior no causo el SIGSEGV, esto lo hará.

La solución es sencilla, supongo que lo que querías era copiar la cadena, esto
lo haces usando [`strcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy).

```c
strcpy(word, "z");
```